# How do I use a doubly linked list to create a sorted list?

Tags: sorting, doubly-linked-list

I need to create a sorted linked list out of this doubly linked list. Also, for some reason, my random number generator isn't generating random numbers. Everything else works just fine.

I've tried multiple random number generators that I've found online, but the list is always a count down from the upper number to 0, instead of multiple random numbers.

```
//main.cpp
 //Random Number seed set once here
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int> (time(NULL)));

    //Declare and initialize variables
    Node *head = new Node();
    head = head->fillNode(rand() % 10 + 1);

    //Print Normal List
    cout << "Original List" << endl;
    head->printNode();
    cout << endl << endl;

//Node.h
Node *Node::fillNode(int n) {
    //Initialize the front
    Node * head;
    Node * tail;
    head = this;
    head->data = n--;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->prev = NULL;
    tail = head;
    //Loop until filled
    do {
        Node *next = new Node;
        // make the new node point to the current tail of the list
        Node *prev = tail;
        next->data = n--;
        next->next = NULL;
        tail->next = next;
        tail = next;
    } while (n >= 0);
    return head;
}
```

I expect the output to be the numbers 0 through 10 in random order. However, I keep getting the numbers 0 through 10 starting from a random point upper number and always counting down to zero. (I.e. 543210 or 3210).

Comment: Can you share the code that randomizes the list? Here it just seeds the PRNG.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted my test code. I added the random number generator in main.cpp: head = head->fillNode(rand() % 10 + 1);